# Reason to include javascript with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I started working on a project a came across a strange way to include a CSS file using javascript.

Example from the project:

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plugins/jquery.datatables.css" />');
```

Is there any reason (advantage) to include the file this way?

Comment: that is a css file, not js

Comment: @TudorConstantin There also js files included this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS file will only be added to the page if the user has JavaScript enabled. Bandwidth saver.

Comment: How does this affect anyone in 2016? It's a text file.

Comment: @Gendarme - Today it's probably more an issue with mobile users who have to watch their data usage.

Answer (score 2):

This code does not include JavaScript but the CSS include...by using JavaScript. It allows to dynamically select your CSS maybe to select themes or adapt layout to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to load the stylesheet only when dataTable is displayed and avoid unnecessary request ?